# Join Find and Foreach retrieving wrong data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, join, foreach, find

I'm working on a join/find Laravel DB to retrieve the correct data, but it is showing the last entry of the database repeated 13 times.

I hope you can help me.
Here is the code.

In controller

```
        $joinCot = Cotizaciones::findOrFail($id);

        $joinCot = DB::table('cotizaciones')->join('prod_cotizaciones', 'prod_cotizaciones.id_cotizacion', '=', 'cotizaciones.id')
                                                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'cotizaciones.id_usuario')
                                                ->join('clientes', 'clientes.id', '=', 'cotizaciones.id_cliente')
                                                ->select('cotizaciones.id', 'cotizaciones.id_usuario', 'cotizaciones.id_cliente', 'cotizaciones.equipo', 'cotizaciones.servicio_venta', 'cotizaciones.pdf', 'cotizaciones.fecha', 'cotizaciones.status', 'prod_cotizaciones.id as idPC', 'prod_cotizaciones.partida as partida', 'users.id as idU', 'clientes.id as idC', 'clientes.nombre_cliente')->get();
```

In blade

```
                @foreach ($joinCot as $key => $value)
                <div>{{ $joinCot->idPC }}</div>
                @endforeach
```

If I make a return of $joinCot it shows

```
[{"id":40,"id_usuario":1,"id_cliente":1,"equipo":"Pipeta","servicio_venta":"Servicio","pdf":null,"fecha":"2021-05-27","status":"Pendiente","idPC":27,"partida":1,"idU":1,"idC":1,"nombre_cliente":"Instituto Nacional de Enfermedades Respiratorias Ismael Cos\u00edo Villegas"},{"id":40,"id_usuario":1,"id_cliente":1,"equipo":"Pipeta","servicio_venta":"Servicio","pdf":null,"fecha":"2021-05-27","status":"Pendiente","idPC":28,"partida":2,"idU":1,"idC":1,"nombre_cliente":"Instituto Nacional de Enfermedades Respiratorias Ismael Cos\u00edo Villegas"}]
```

I have 2 entries with idPC = 27 and the second one with idPC = 28.

But at the time to return the view the foreach just throws 28282828282828282828282828.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing wrong on inside loop `$joinCot->idPC`  it should be `$value->idPC`.`$value`  will return each row from array or object.

```
@if(isset($joinCot)&&count((array)$joinCot))
    @foreach ($joinCot as $key => $value)
                <div>{{$value->idPC }}</div>
                @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: it gives me Trying to get property 'idPC' of non-object error

Comment: @AlanVazquez first dd($joinCot) and check what you get if its array then you need to access like $value['idPc']

Comment: @AlanVazquez.i have updated answer.also post full method of controller so i can see what you are passing to view

Comment: I had overriding data.
Now it is solved, thanks.

Comment: @AlanVazquez.great to here you have solved issue

Answer (score 0):

$joinCot is your retrieved data array. foreach() return single row and key in every iteration. You have to access row->value.
That means,

```
@foreach ($joinCot as $key => $value)
   <div>{{$value->idPC }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it gives me Trying to get property 'idPC' of non-object error